# regex search and replace with modified result

Tags: python, regex

I have a string with tagged elements inside. I want to remove the tags and add some characters to the content inside the tags.

```
s = 'Hello there <something>, this is more text <tagged content>'
result = 'Hello there somethingADDED, this is more text tagged contentADDED
```

So far, I've tried

```
import re
result = re.search('\<(.*)\>', s)
result = result.group(1)
```

and `s =  s.split('>')` and regex each substring one by one, but it doesn't seem like the correct or efficient way of doing this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `back-reference` `\1`.

```
x="Hello there <something>, this is more text <tagged content>"
print re.sub(r"<([^>]*)>",r"\1added",x)
```

Output :`Hello there somethingadded, this is more text tagged contentadded`

Comment: i think he doesn't need the "ADDED" part... it's just a way that he finds to show he wanna add `something` and  add `content`